# PHP | fputcsv : generated file only populated with field header, but no records

Tags: php, fputcsv

I can't figure out why this code only generate a file with the field headers, but no records.

File content :

```
"Article ID",Shoppergroupname,"Promotion Price",VAT-Code,"Article Currency","Promotion Start Date","Promotion End Date"
```

As you can see, no record are "exported" and database table is not tempty !

By the way I also would like to get rid of the field header quotes.

Would appreciate if someone would help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Marc

SOLUTION PROVIDED BY @KateMihalikova

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($databasehost, $databaseusername, $databasepassword, $databasename);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully | ";

// Create filename
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');
$today = date("YmdHis"); 
$csvname = "WS_PRICE_IMPORT-".$today.".csv";
$csvfullname = '/var/.../'.$csvname; 


// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen($csvfullname, 'a+');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Article ID', 'Shoppergroupname', 'Promotion Price', 'VAT-Code', 'Article Currency', 'Promotion Start Date', 'Promotion End Date'));

 // fetch the data
$sql = "SELECT `Article ID`, `Shoppergroupname`, `Promotion Price`, `VAT-Code`, `Article Currency`, `Promotion Start Date`, `Promotion End Date` FROM jos_temppriceimport";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "Unable to execute query in the database : " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
echo "No record found, no record to export in CSV.";
exit;
}

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

PS: Fieldname with space are delivered by the dataprovider.

Comment: What's the `if ($conn->query($row) ....`  code block supposed to do? a) it looks like pdo or mysqli while the other code uses the deprecated mysql_* extension. b) $row must be false/null after the while loop.

Comment: @VolkerK thanks, is it better now ?

Comment: You are still mixing mysql and mysqli, try `$result->fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)`.

Comment: @KateMihalikova thank you correction made, but query still not work

Comment: It's possible that your code fails on `mysql_num_rows`, change it to `$result->num_rows`. You can also add some `echo`s here and there to help with debugging.

Comment: @KateMihalikova thanks I just made a print_r of the resultats :

    mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 7 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 4 [type] => 0 ) 

I have 4 records in my database table. But this records are still not exported in the CSV file, only the field header are.

Comment: Change fputcsv to var_dump. If it works, the problem is in fputcsv itself.

Comment: @KateMihalikova thanks 

Var_dump output is :

    `resource(4) of type (stream) array(7) { [0]=> string(10) "Article ID" [1]=> string(16) "Shoppergroupname" [2]=> string(15) "Promotion Price" [3]=> string(8) "VAT-Code" [4]=> string(16) "Article Currency" [5]=> string(20) "Promotion Start Date" [6]=> string(18) "Promotion End Date" }`

Records are found but not exported...

Comment: OK, try to save some other data to csv (i.e. save the header twice) to see if it saves correctly. You also can try changing fetch_assoc to fetch_row.

Comment: @KateMihalikova thanks again, tried to export users change fetch_assoc to fetch_row but only the headers are still exported

   `Name,Username,Email`

Comment: Does it work with `fputcsv($output, array($row[0]));`?

Comment: @KateMihalikova thanks, tested but doesn't work

Comment: What about simple `fputcsv($output, array("TEST"));` after the `while` loop, does it save into the file?

Comment: @KateMihalikova yes it saved the "TEST" value in the file

Comment: Let's try `while ($row = $result->fetch_row($result)) {fputs($output, "TEST1\n"); fputs($output, "TEST2" . array_join("+", $row) . "\n"); fputcsv($output, array("TEST3");}`

Comment: @KateMihalikova thank you for your time Kate. New while loop doesn't generate anything. File isn't created...

Comment: OK, I've tried running it myself now and the only error thrown was that you need to change `$result->fetch_row($result)` to `$result->fetch_row()`. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jcbx-7c0n

Comment: @KateMihalikova thanks a lot it is working now, I appreciate, I've learn a few things. Take care.

Comment: I'm glad we worked it out, please mark the answer which helped you the most as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your code was mixing of procedural `mysql`, procedural `mysqli`, and object-oriented `mysqli`. They are similar, but can't be mixed.

We sort out that the main problem was in while loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

after iterating a little, there was a problem with object-oriented notation, where object methods are used instead of functions with attributes, but that attribute was left there. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jcbx-7c0n

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row($result)) fputcsv($output, $row); // forgotten attribute
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) fputcsv($output, $row);        // working just fine
```

Comment: Yes my code was a "mess" ! I'm a newbie, so I need to improve my skills, what I could do today thanks to you. The next time I will write my queries more carefully, appropriately and respect conventions. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over your SQL statement. You need to loop through your result instead.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```